# R: removing NAs in numerical vectors

Tags: r

I am an R novice and am having some challenges.  I am dealing with a large dataframe which I have read from a csv file.  My numerical vectors contain NAs which are stopping me from running analyses.  How do I get rid of these NAs so I can actually do something with my data?

Comment: Try the http://RSeek.org website for queries this.

Comment: And before rseeking make sure you read [R Introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html), [missing values](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Missing-values).

Answer (score 8):

- for particular variable:
  `x[!is.na(x)]`, or `na.omit` (see `apropos("^na\\.")` for all available `na.` functions),
- within function, pass `na.rm = TRUE`
  as an argument e.g. `sapply(dtf, sd,
  na.rm = TRUE)`,
- set global NA action:
  `options(na.action = "na.omit")`
  which is set by default, but many
  functions don't rely on globally
  defined NA action (`mean` for
  instance), while some do (right now I
  cannot come up with an example),
- and, of, course, if you have a lot of
  NA's, you should consider variable
  imputation, there's a [question asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613420/handling-missing-incomplete-data-in-r-is-there-function-to-mask-but-not-remove-n/2994546) that can be helpful.

Long story short, dealing with NA's is a very broad problem, try to concretize it a bit and give us a concise question. I'm sure that someone of SOers can help you!

Cheers, lad!

Comment: `complete.cases` is useful too.

Answer (score 5):

```
na.omit(dataFrame)
```

This is an awesome website that I use for quick R related information: http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using na.omit() function.

```
myVec <- na.omit(myVec)
```