# Coding Missing Data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset where inspection of the data shows some of the following, all of which should be missing

```
'missing'
'unknown'
'uncoded'
```

Am I correct in thinking that I can just replace all occurrences of these with "NA" ? Is this the preferred way of doing it ?

```
var[var=='missing'] <- NA
var[var=='unknown'] <- NA
var[var=='uncoded'] <- NA
```

Comment: The "preferred" way most likely depends on the analysis you're trying to do, and so you might get a lot of opinion answers. Perhaps rephrasing the question to something like "How can R represent missing data" might help. However, the answer to that question is probably already out there.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that missing data was always represented as NA ? I've always just dealt with data that was already coded as NA, but this time I have these other codings.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know whether you were referring to the preferred way of recoding or the preferred way of dealing with missing values. If you're sure you want to code them as `NA`, then you could also consider `NA_character_`, `NA_integer_` etc (listed under `?"NA"`)

Comment: BenBarnes , sorry. To clarify, I am referring to the way of coding missing data. Actually I am going to use the `mice` package to impute these missing values. I am teaching myself R and don't have very much experience yet.

Comment: Of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335745/how-do-i-handle-multiple-kinds-of-missingness-in-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you show is feasible, but you can simplify your code to a single call doing the comparison via the `%in%` binary operator. Here is an example using some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
var <- factor(sample(c("missing","unknown","uncoded", 1:4), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

This gives us a factor vector like this:

```
> head(var)
[1] unknown uncoded 2       4       unknown 4      
Levels: 1 2 3 4 missing uncoded unknown
> table(var)
var
      1       2       3       4 missing uncoded unknown 
     14      15      17      13      10      18      13
```

To set all those values coded as any of `c("missing","unknown","uncoded")` to `NA`, we do it in a single shot:

```
var2 <- var ## copy for demo purposes, but you can over write if you wish
var2[var2 %in% c("missing","unknown","uncoded")] <- NA
```

which gives

```
> var2[var2 %in% c("missing","unknown","uncoded")] <- NA
> head(var2)
[1] <NA> <NA> 2    4    <NA> 4   
Levels: 1 2 3 4 missing uncoded unknown
> table(var2)
var2
      1       2       3       4 missing uncoded unknown 
     14      15      17      13       0       0       0
```

Notice how the original levels are preserved. If you want to remove those levels then we can apply the `droplevels()` function to `var2`:

```
var2 <- droplevels(var2)
```

which gives

```
> head(var2)
[1] <NA> <NA> 2    4    <NA> 4   
Levels: 1 2 3 4
> table(var2)
var2
 1  2  3  4 
14 15 17 13
```

Also note that by default the `NA` are not shown in the tabular output, but we rectify that to show you that they are still there:

```
> table(var2, useNA = "ifany")
var2
   1    2    3    4 <NA> 
  14   15   17   13   41
```

Answer (score 4):

The general idea of replacing them with NA is correct.

You can use `recode` if you want to do it in a single line:

```
library(car)
var <- recode( var, "c('missing','unknown','uncoded')=NA" )
```